# How to specify JMS username and password within URL

Tags: activemq-classic

I have an application which connects to ActiveMQ using a "failover" URL string. The admins are adding authentication to the brokers. Is it possible to put `jms.userName` and `jms.password` into the URL string?  An example with dummy values would be most helpful.

Comment: Keep in mind that any passwords in clear text will be fundamentally insecure which is typically fine for development purposes, but it would be highly discouraged in any kind of production scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly how you specified it works. The jms. prefix configures any of the setters on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory.

```
failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)?jms.userName=admin&jms.password=admin
```

Log confirmation:

```
09:41:53.429 INFO [ActiveMQ Task-1] Successfully connected to tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
09:41:53.481 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Route: route1 started and consuming from: amq://queue:VQ.ORDER.VT.ORDER.EVENT
```